# Change file name to a username

Tags: php, html, css

How can I change my file called profile.php to a username on my site.

I want it to be like instead of www.website.com/profile.php?id=1, then I want it to be like www.website.com/username - how can I do that?

Please help me - this is for my final exame.

Comment: You need to look into url rewriting.

Comment: This question has been asked before.  There are a lot of options in the answers:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php